# Dynamic lists in puppet?

Tags: puppet

I am using puppet (version 4.x, where 2 <= x <= 8) to configure a system.  I have a number of variables provided by Hiera, each containing a list of groups.  The input data looks something like:

```
project1_groups:
  - group1
  - group2

project2_groups:
  - group2
  - group3

project3_groups:
  - group2
  - group4
```

From this, I need to build a single list of groups that I can pass to a `user` resource.  Conceptually, I want:

```
$groups = project1_groups + project2_groups + project3_groups
user { 'someuser':
  groups => $groups
}
```

In other words, from the above input data I want to get a list of groups that might look something like:

```
[group1, group2, group2, group3, group2, group4]
```

Dupes are okay, the list does not have to be unique-ified.

But there is a complication! The trick is that I do not know in advance the available `project*_groups` variables. I have  a variable `$projects` that in the above example would contain the list `[project1, project2, project3]`.

I've come up with an `inline_template` based solution that works but seems hacky; I am wondering if there is a better way of doing this:

```
include stdlib

# get the list of project names
$projects = hiera('projects')

# this is a list of default groups. It might be undefined.
$default_groups = undef

# create a comma-delimited list of groups
$groups_string = inline_template('<% @projects.each do |prj|
    -%><% scope.call_function("hiera",
        [prj + "_groups", []]).each do |grp|
    -%><%= grp %>,<% end -%><% end -%>')

# start with a (possibly nil) list of default groups
$_groups = any2array($default_groups)

# split comma-delimited string, concatenate it with default groups,
# and remove empty groups (which you get if $default_groups is nil).
$groups = concat($_groups, $groups_string.split(',')).filter |$grp| {$grp != ''}
```

**Note** Updated to use `scope.call_function`, since you can't call `hiera` as `scope.function_hiera` in puppet 4.x.

Comment: Which puppet version? Also, not sure if I got this right: Your code seems to join the arrays, which would result in duplicated groups, like `group1, group2, group2, group3, group2, group4`. Is this to be expected?

Comment: It is expected that this creates a single list of groups, yes, because that is what is required by the `groups` key on the `user` resource. It is also expected that there may be duplicates in the list, and that is okay.  This is puppet version 4.x, where 2 <= x <= 8.